# Proving that a simple Sequence Converges

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $\left|a_n -A\right| \le b_n$ for all very large n and that $b_n \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty.$  Prove that $a_n \rightarrow A.$

I am having trouble getting started here.  I clearly need to use the definition of convergence for a sequence.  Also, we know that since $b_n \rightarrow 0$ then {$b_n$} must be bounded.

I need to show that for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a natural number N such that for all $n \in N$, $n > N$ implies that $\left| a_n-A \right|$ < $\epsilon$.

I'm horrible at this stuff.  Any hints would be much appreciated.  I have a feeling that we should also be using the triangle inequality.

Thank you!!!

Comment: By definition, what does the fact that $b_n\to 0$ imply?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon>0$. We have the $b_n\to 0$, therefore, there exist a $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $|b_n|<\varepsilon$ if $n\geq N$. Moreover,
$$|a_n-A|\leq |b_n|,$$
therefore, if $n\geq N$, 
$$|a_n-A|\leq |b_n|<\varepsilon$$
and thus
$$|a_n-A|<\varepsilon$$
if $n\geq N$.

We have proved that for all $\varepsilon>0$, there exist a $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $|a_n-A|<\varepsilon$ if $n\geq N$, and thus $a_n\to A$.

Comment: $\text{Git :P}$

Comment: Thank you very much.  A simple proof that my neanderthal-like brain could not put into fruition.

Answer (score 2):

Given $\epsilon>0 \quad \exists m\in\Bbb{N}$ st we have $|b_n|<\epsilon \quad \forall n\ge m$ ,thus $|a_n-A|<\epsilon \quad \forall n\ge m$ i.e $a_n \to A$
So we observe that given $\epsilon>0$ same natural number $m$ works for $\{a_n\}$ also.

Answer (score 0):

Okay this isn't too bad.

If: $\forall\epsilon>0\exists N\in\mathbb{N}:n>N\implies|a_n-A|<\epsilon$ then $a_n\rightarrow A$.

This is just the definition.

You know that $\forall\epsilon>0\exists N_b\in\mathbb{N}:n_b>N_b\implies|b_{n_b}-0|=|b_{n_b}|<\epsilon$ - this is the definition of $b_n\rightarrow 0$

So:

let $\epsilon>0$ be given. You need to find an N such that whenever n>N we have $|a_n-A|\le B_n\le|B_n|<\epsilon$

Which comes right from definitions.

Comment: Downvoter, why? With one sentence added to this, the OP has a model answer for their homework.